# jQuery fn to npm package

Tags: jquery, npm

Let's take the tutorial from jQuery to create a new jQuery plugin. Below a copy-paste from the tutorial mentioned at https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

```
(function ( $ ) {

  $.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
    return this;
  };

}( jQuery ));
```

I'd like to use this plugin in my npm driven website where I use several other npm packages. Below is an example of how I would like to use "greenify".

```
import $ from 'jquery'

export default function popup() {

  $('.some-selector').greenify();

}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've figured it out. Don't know if it's the right way, but it works :)

I've followed the guide I've found at the npm website, see https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules and changed the plugin code to below:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  greenify: function () {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
    return this;
  }
});
```

In my other file I now can use my 'greenify' function with following code:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import greenify from 'jquery-greenify'

export default function popup() {

  $('.some-selector').greenify();

}
```